# (click) funtion not triggering in chrome angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, google-chrome

(click) funtion not triggering in my select tag when i use google chrome but its works in mozila

this is my code

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-9">
    <select formControlName="deptId" class="form-control m-input" >
    <option>SELECT</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of listAllDepartment"  (click)="getdoctorlistid(item.dept_id)" value={{item.dept_id}}>{{item.dept_name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do on clicking of particular option.

Comment: i want call getdoctorlistid() funtion

Comment: Yes, but in  that function what you are doing because you can do things on change of select event also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngModelChange with select instead of  click

```
 <selectformControlName="deptId" class="form-control m-input"  [(ngModel)]="itemSelected" (ngModelChange)="getdoctorlistid(itemSelected)">
```

Comment: I guess one space is missing: "<select formControlName..."

Answer (score 0):

You **can't add** such an event to an `<option>`
You can add

```
<select 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" 
    (ngModelChange)="getdoctorlistid(selectedItem)">
        <option>SELECT</option>
        <option 
            *ngFor="let item of listAllDepartment"  
            (click)="getdoctorlistid(item.dept_id)" 
            value={{item.dept_id}}>
                {{item.dept_name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

**Edit**: Like @Sajeetharan answered